# question about string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am doing a python question where if there is a non alphanumeric character between 2 alpha numeric characters, it should be replaced with a single space ' '. As seen below. This is only for non-alpha chars BETWEEN 2 alpha chars, in the case below its between 'this and is', and 'is and matrix', the last half (non alph chars) shoudl stay untouched. How do i go about doing this.

Your Output:

```
'This$#is% Matrix#  %!'
```

Expected Output:

```
'This is Matrix#  %!'
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code. Hope this will help you.

import  re

a ='This$#is% Matrix#  %!'

b= re.sub(r'([\w])([\W]{1,})([\w])',r'\1 \3',a )

print(b)